# Webchart control Devexpress currency

Tags: asp.net, iis, devexpress

I'm currently developing on ASP.NET C# and also I'm using devexpress controls to display charts in a intranet.

Everything seems to work perfectly fine on my end, my computer is window 7 and it has the devexpress components installed in it. Also the server has the devexpress components installed (Server: Windows 8 R2).

To share the ASPX page I use the IIS server, I activated the IIS on my computer and the local server too.

When I run the project from visual studio everything looks OK.

When users access the ASPX page from my IP's computer or the local server. The currency does not look OK.

Here you are some screenshot comparisons:

Image when visual studio runs ---

[image: Chart OK]

Image when accesing the IIS servers.

[image: Chart misleading]

Is there anything I can do to solve this inconvenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the currency format of your IIS server machine and then you need to restart the IIS server so that the changes take effect.

**Steps to change currency format:**

1. Change date and time settings in IIS Server machine
2. Click on Change date and time
3. Click on Change calendar settings
4. Go to currency tab
5. Change Digit grouping drop down list as you want
6. Apply all the changes

Now you can access your web application.

Comment: I accessed ASP.NET Global and changed the currency.